# If I delete an item after changing the input number, the final result is calculated incorrectly. Where is the problem?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't know how to multiply the input number by the item price and then delete it from the final amount

```
  const deleteItem = (index) => {
    setWarenKorb((prev) => {
       // Löschen Sie das Artikelobjekt aus dem Warenkorb
       const newWarenKorb = prev.filter((_, i) => i !== index);
   
       // Aktualisieren Sie den Gesamtpreis, indem Sie den Preis des zu löschenden Artikels subtrahieren
       warenkorbPreisChanger((prev) => (prev = prev - parseInt((warenKorb[index].price)) * inputZahlen[index])); // aktualsiert preis
   
       return newWarenKorb;
    });
   };

  

  // Initialisiere den Zustand als leeres Objekt
  const [inputZahlen, setInputZahlen] = useState({});

  const inputPlus = (index) => {
    setInputZahlen((prev) => ({ ...prev, [index]: (prev[index] || 0) + 1 }));
    warenkorbPreisChanger((prev) => (prev = prev + warenKorb[index].price)); // aktualsiert preis
  };

  const inputMinus = (index) => {
    setInputZahlen((prev) => {
      if ((prev[index] || 0) > 1) {
        return { ...prev, [index]: (prev[index] || 0) - 1 };
      } else {
        return prev;
      }
    });
    warenkorbPreisChanger((prev) => (prev = prev - warenKorb[index].price)); // aktualsiert preis
  };
```

I couldn't solve the problem with Ai

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It might be easier for the other users to understand your code and help you if you translate your code to English.